# Dropbox error: Failed to open popup window

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am experiencing a confusing error (for me it is confusing since I am new to this sort of thing, and I cannot find any good tutorials on it either) when I try to integrate a Dropbox saver into my webpage. The webpage is built using MVC4. The problem I am experiencing is that when I click on the "Save to Dropbox" button, I get the following error in dropins.js:

"Failed to open a popup window. Dropbox.choose and Dropbox.save should only be called from within a user-triggered event handler such as a tap or click event."

What does it mean? How must I rewrite my code to make this work? I've even tried making a button that calls Dropbox.save(), but the same error pops up.

So, the code:

```
// Button to open the saver dialog.
<button onclick="openSaveDialog();">Save</button>

// Javascript function.
function openSaveDialog() {
    window.open('@Url.Action("SaveDialog")', '_blank');
}

// Controller function called by the above Javascript function.
public ActionResult SaveDialog()
{
    return View();
}

// Here is the code for the save dialog. Note that the key to the Dropbox javascript link has been omitted for my safety ;)
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Save</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="<key omitted for safety>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="save">
    <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/deroi5nwm6u7gdf/advice.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice is warmly welcome... been scratching my head at this for a good two days now, trying to find any tutorials at all.

Comment: Hmm, moving from my popup-page to a "real page" (i.e. the page where I triggered the openSaveDialog() function), I get no error in the dropbox script about a popup, but I get another error now:

"Unable to communicate with parent window."

What can this be caused by?

Comment: There are a few different things that can cause the "Unable to communicate with parent window." issue. What sort of environment are you running this in? E.g., is this just running on a normal web page in a desktop browser, or is this bundled into a mobile app using a framework?

Comment: It is an MVC4 project running on an IIS, so your first one "normal web page in a desktop browser".

Comment: Thanks! In that case, please open a ticket so we can help track this down: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact